# How to control JMF cache size?

Tags: java, caching, jmf

I can set the cache either On or Off, which are not very good choices since the default cache seems to be huge and setting caching completely off creates other problems.

```
player = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(channelURL));
Manager.setHint(Manager.CACHING, new Boolean(false)); // this will disable buffering
player.start();
```

But is there anyway to define the cache size? It's not discussed much in the documentation..

Comment: *"the default cache seems to be huge"*  Why is that a problem?

Comment: *"It's not discussed much in the documentation.."*  You can **find** documentation on JMF?  Huh..  using the [wayback machine](http://archive.org/web/)?

Comment: Yes there is some old documentation on oracle's site. And a huge buffer is a problem because it will buffer the audio for 40sec-1min before starting to play it. Then again if you turn it completely off  it'll start the stream quickly but the player sometimes gets messed up if it can't load the stream instantly..